# How do I get the creation date of a MySQL view?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to export views from one database to import into another.

I use the following to get the view definitions:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, VIEW_DEFINITION
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database_name';
```

The problem is that the order the views are created is important due to dependencies.

I think a solution would be to select the view names in order of the view creation dates.

1) How do I get the creation date of a MySQL view?

2) Is there a better way to allow views to be created where the dependencies are not yet met?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to get that info. But as a quick workaround you can do

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ...
```

instead of `CREATE VIEW...` and run this for all views multiple times till there are no more errors.